# How to convert Pinescript version 2 to Version 5?

Tags: pine-script

I found this code by chart art, I need only fastcolor variable from this. I am building my own strategy and I would love this feature in mine. It provides better confirmation for my entry signals. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you all in advance.

```
//@version=2    
// Input
fastlen = input(12, title="Fast Moving Average")
slowlen = input(26, title="Slow Moving Average")
signallen = input(9, title="Signal Line")
switch1=input(true, title="Enable Bar Color?")
switch2=input(true, title="Enable Moving Averages?")
switch3=input(true, title="Enable Heatmap?")

// Calculation
fast = ema(close,fastlen)
slow = ema(close,slowlen)
MACD = fast - slow
signal = ema(MACD, signallen)
histogr = MACD - signal

// MACD, MA colors
MACDcolor = fast > slow ? green : red
fastcolor = change(fast) > 0 ? green : red
slowcolor = change(slow) > 0 ? green : red
MACDupdowncolor = change(MACD) > 0 ? green : red
```

Error:

```
Could not find function or function reference 'ema'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the translation of your code snippet to v5, but your script is incomplete because there's no output (no plot). I added one.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=false)

// Input
fastlen = input(12, title="Fast Moving Average")
slowlen = input(26, title="Slow Moving Average")
signallen = input(9, title="Signal Line")
switch1=input(true, title="Enable Bar Color?")
switch2=input(true, title="Enable Moving Averages?")
switch3=input(true, title="Enable Heatmap?")

// Calculation
fast = ta.ema(close,fastlen)
slow = ta.ema(close,slowlen)
MACD = fast - slow
signal = ta.ema(MACD, signallen)
histogr = MACD - signal

// MACD, MA colors
MACDcolor = fast > slow ? color.green : color.red
fastcolor = ta.change(fast) > 0 ? color.green : color.red
slowcolor = ta.change(slow) > 0 ? color.green : color.red
MACDupdowncolor = ta.change(MACD) > 0 ? color.green : color.red

plot(MACD, color=MACDcolor, style=plot.style_histogram)
```